# can i create a login screen which will check for passwords and usernames from a table in a database

Tags: netbeans6.5

does anyone have a code for login screen that can register a new user and also login users that exist in a table in a database?
i would appreciate very much any form of help

Answer (score 2):

there is a well-know solution to this problem:

http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/60/nbm-login.html